# how to run metro webservice on jetty in Maven project?

Tags: web-services, jetty

how to run metro webservice on jetty in Maven project??

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=64807) source.

If you place your web service in a WAR file, like [here](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/creating_a_wsdl_first_web1), it should run fine
on Jetty, just as it would on any servlet container. There might be some
subsequent Jetty-specific configuration needed, but I would try to deploy
the WAR first on Jetty and see where it gets you.

If you want to *embed* Jetty, instead of running on Jetty standalone, [this](http://www.jroller.com/gmazza/entry/writing_junit_test_cases_for#testjt)
might give you some pointers.

Comment: We run Metro 1.4 in an embedded Jetty 6 here under Java 5.  Works fine.  Note:  The Metro jars goes in the jetty lib, not the war.